# How to pass data from one page model to another page model in fresh mvmm

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have used Fresh MVMM. I need to pass a data from one page model to another page model without using init and reverse init.
Eg: I have one toggle button in first content page.
I need to toggled the button based on the selection in second popup page without popup the second PopPopupPageModel.
ReverseInit is worked when popup the second PopPopupPageModel and can easily pass data.
But I need to toogled the button in first page without popup the second page.
Please help...

Comment: just instantiate an instance of model B and get the value from it?

Comment: When asking a question, please show all relevant code and xaml - its much easier to give useful help when seeing some code. Here, you could show the declaration of the button. And the code you would do ("can easily pass data") if the button were in the same page. Also maybe google `pass data from one page model to another page model in fresh mvmm`.